# How to fill the text field on web-page?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I need to fill the text field on internal site SharePoint in my company. But when I start my code, before the filling me value next error raise:

> Run-time error: Automation Error, The interface is unknown

Please help

```
Sub Authority()

Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = True

ie.navigate "OurInternalSite"

ie.document.getelementbyid("TextField5").Value = "My text"

End Sub
```

Code of button

```
<input data-is-interactable="true" id="ComboBox29-input" class="ms-ComboBox-Input css-93" type="text" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="inline" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" data-lpignore="true" value="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't waited for the page to load which has likely led to this error

```
ie.navigate "site"
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState<>4:DoEvents:Wend
```

The id for the `input` is also

```
ComboBox29-input
```

Comment: About id I agree with you. But on the step While ie.Busy...wend error "The object invoked has disconnected from its clients" raise

Comment: That becomes a different error.  Notice how your interface unknown is now resolved. Please give the exact new error message.